# sharing session between roundcube and owncloud via memcache

Tags: session, share, roundcube, owncloud

I have an owncloud and a roundcube sharing the same session pool via a memcache server and I would like them to work with an unique session.

I changed the cookie session.name to have the same for owncloud and roundcube and I tried a lot of tricks: to pass the session id then the session name via url, to change the $_SESSION['user_id' in roundcube because owncloud has the same variable, to avoid the cookie creation in the session_init from roundcube, etc...

But, the roundcube session always erase the owncloud one which causes owncloud not to login anymore.

What is the trick ? Is there a method somewhere to do that ?

I use the 'RoundcubeLogin.class.php' to perform the login from owncloud to roundcube but it creates separate sessions for each.

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to share the session? What do you want to achive?
If you're just wanting to avoid another login, you can use the same login for roundcube or owncloud and use the auto-login feature

Comment: Please put this to comment.